# Mistakenly ran "sudo apt-get remove python" (system is not working in normal mode, is there any solution?)

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, apt-get

By mistake I ran the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove python
```

After this my PC is no longer working properly.

It shows graphics problem during restarting and every time it starts in Grub loader mode

Is there any solution to recover it back into normal mode so that I don't need to reconfigure all the settings of my packages?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear that. Maybe there is a silver bullet out there, but it should be better to reinstall the whole thing.

I haven't tried this approach (obviously), but it shouldn't worsen the situation:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your positive response but i have tried that but that command is not working in my case, I am doing with "sudo apt-get upgrade"                             If u have any other way then please reply me as early as possible.

Comment: Try this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10029998&postcount=6. Original thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1606409

Comment: Thanks a lot for these links as second link has the same problem as i have, and may be that will help me to solve my problem. I will come back to you shortly.........

Answer (score 0):

Settings shouldn't be effected by this at all. The problem you're now facing is, that pretty big parts of the userland<sup>1</sup> have been removed.

How to recover this mess? Well, if you can, boot up to the Login-Screen and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. If it doesn't boot anymore to the login screen, boot into the "Recovery Console", which is selectable in the Grub bootmenu. From there it's pretty straight forward:

- Login
- Make sure you're connected to a network, if not, connect to one
- Reinstall the core of Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`
- Reboot

<sup>1</sup>: Yes, userland. In the list of Robert Smiths list is no *real* system package, so the basic system is fine.